# SQL Server - Find Gaps Between Dates that Include Overlapping Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was recently tasked with finding gaps between dates of employments, where a gap is         defined as having a time span of greater than 30 days from the end of one job to the start of the next, and was able to come up with a query to suit that, see below:

```
WITH GapsInEmployment AS
(
    SELECT 
    -1 AS DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentGapId
    ,E1.DriverQualificationApplicationId
    ,E1.EndDate AS EmploymentGapBeginDate
    ,E2.StartDate AS EmploymentGapEndDate
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DD, E1.EndDate, E2.StartDate), 0) < 0 THEN 0
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DD, E1.EndDate, E2.StartDate)
        END
        ) AS DaysLapsedBetweenEmployment
        ,NULL AS ReasonForEmploymentGap
    FROM @EmploymentGapInfo E1
    LEFT JOIN @EmploymentGapInfo E2 
        ON E1.RowNum = E2.RowNum - 1
)

SELECT *
FROM GapsInEmployment
WHERE DaysLapsedBetweenEmployment > 30;
```

I'm doing a comparison of one record, to the next record, to see if there's an lapse of 30 days between the end date of the first record and the start date of the second one, which works fine for "normal" cases, i.e. where periods of employment don't overlap. Well that particular case has appeared where someone has more than one job during a particular time period, and the time period of Job A is between the period of time that the employee had Job B. Here's the test data to run with the query above:

```
DECLARE @EmploymentGapInfo TABLE
(
    RowNum INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId INT
    ,DriverQualificationApplicationId INT
    ,StartDate DATETIME
    ,EndDate DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO @EmploymentGapInfo
SELECT -1, 766, '10/14/2003', '11/07/2003';

INSERT INTO @EmploymentGapInfo
SELECT -1, 766, '08/28/2006', '06/15/2011';

INSERT INTO @EmploymentGapInfo
SELECT -1, 766, '08/22/2011', '10/23/2012';

INSERT INTO @EmploymentGapInfo
SELECT -1, 766, '06/01/2012', '07/01/2012';

INSERT INTO @EmploymentGapInfo
SELECT -1, 766, '11/01/2012', '03/05/2013';

INSERT INTO @EmploymentGapInfo
SELECT -1, 766, '10/14/2013', NULL;
```

If you run the query, it's incorrectly calculating an employment gap between 07/01/2012 and 11/01/2012, which is incorrect as the start date and end date for that record starts between the previous record. The query should produce the following result set for the gaps:

11/07/2003 -> 08/28/2006

06/15/2011 -> 08/22/2011

03/05/2013 -> 10/14/2013

My problem is, I'm trying to come up with a way to calculate this correctly without a cursor, as the way I've been trying would involve me looping through each record in the EmploymentGapInfo table variable, and once I have the start and end dates for that record, loop through the table again to see if the start date and end date overlap any other records in the table.

Is there any way I can tackle this problem with a set-based approach instead of trying to use a cursor? Would this be a problem that would benefit from having it done in the business layer versus trying to solve it in the database?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try creating an [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) Demo and give the link here

Comment: The last gap (`03/05/2013 -> 10/14/2013`) is wrong because there is this row `'10/14/2012 -> NULL`.

Comment: @th1rdey3: Here is the link to the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06753/3/0

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: Sorry, that should've read 10/14/2013, the mistake has been corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Great solution for sql server 2012 and above. All the credit to A Boucher on ask tom https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:529176000346581356

```
select *
from (
      select 
       max(enddate) over (order by startdate) start_range
       ,lead(startdate) over (order by startdate) end_range
      from @EmploymentGapInfo
    ) as c
where c.start_range < c.end_range
```

Comment: I know this is really old, but I just wanted to say thank you!  This solved a very similar problem I was having perfectly, and saved me many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table with all the dates of your @EmploymentGapInfo sorted by date in ascending order.After that its more easy to find out the gaps.

The query to get all the dates could look like this :

```
select distinct StartDate 'GDate'
from @EmploymentGapInfo
union
select distinct EndDate 
from @EmploymentGapInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a to old post... but here is the answer:

First of all, you should eliminate the posibility to have overlapping ranges, and express the result in a non overlaped range list. That is not an easy task, you cando it with this query:

```
    SELECT *
    INTO #TEMP
    FROM
    (
          SELECT DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId, DriverQualificationApplicationId, Min(NewStartDate) StartDate, MAX(EndDate) EndDate
          FROM
          (
                SELECT DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId, DriverQualificationApplicationId, StartDate, EndDate,
                      NewStartDate = Range_UNTIL_NULL.StartDate + NUMBERS.number,
                      NewStartDateGroup =     DATEADD(d, 
                                                  1 - DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId, DriverQualificationApplicationId ORDER BY Range_UNTIL_NULL.StartDate + NUMBERS.number), 
                                                  Range_UNTIL_NULL.StartDate + NUMBERS.number)
                FROM 
                (
                      SELECT 
                            DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId, DriverQualificationApplicationId, StartDate, ISNULL(EndDate, dateadd(d,1,StartDate)) AS EndDate
                      FROM @EmploymentGapInfo T1
                      WHERE
                            NOT  EXISTS (   SELECT * 
                                            FROM @EmploymentGapInfo t2 
                                            WHERE  T1.DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId = t2.DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId AND
                                                   T1.DriverQualificationApplicationId = T2.DriverQualificationApplicationId and 
                                                   T1.StartDate > T2.StartDate AND T2.EndDate IS NULL
                                        )
                )  AS Range_UNTIL_NULL
                CROSS APPLY  Enumerate ( ABS(DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, EndDate))) AS NUMBERS
                      ) X
          GROUP BY DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId, DriverQualificationApplicationId, NewStartDateGroup
    ) OVERLAPED_RANGES_WITH_COUNT
    ORDER BY DriverQualificationApplicationEmploymentId, DriverQualificationApplicationId, StartDate
```

And then you can compute Gaps having more than 30 days:

```
SELECT 
    EndDate AS StartGap, 
    ( SELECT MIN(StartDate) FROM #temp t3 WHERE t3.startdate  > t1.endDate) AS EndGap 
FROM #TEMP t1
WHERE EndDate + 30 < (SELECT Min(startDate) FROM #temp t2 WHERE t2.startdate  > t1.endDate)
```